# Почему скорость поиска в хеш таблице и доступ к значению в массиве - константа?

Tags: массивы, алгоритм, хеширование, структуры-данных

Как происходит сопоставление вычисленного hash и конкретной ячейки?

Ситуация с коллизиями понятна, но тут не об этом.

Даже если бы у нас значения были отсортированы, то это был бы логарифм.

Аналогично как происходит доступ к массиву по индексу за константу?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0#%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0_%D1%85%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B

За константу вычисляем хеш. За константу находим нужный бакет

Comment: В разделе "Свойства хеш-таблицы" только декларация таких свойств + упомянут случай когда таблица уже переполнена. Мне интересно как конкретно происходит операция за константу.

Comment: Я же выше написал «как». И там написано что это «в среднем» и «при некоторых допущениях». В худшем случае в зависимости от реализации будет совершенно не константа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В дополнение к ответу выше, доступ к элементу массива по индексу это по сути указание конкретной ячейки памяти. Операция [] представляет собой разыменование указателя, то есть получение значения по этому указателю. Когда мы объявляем массив, мы получаем ссылку (указатель) на его местонахождение в памяти (не вдаваясь в детали реализации, условно ячейка нулевого элемента). Когда мы обращаемся к n-ому элементу, мы просто добавляем n*s байт к ячейке, на которую указывает ссылка, где s - это размерность типа массива в байтах.

Comment: Языки разные бывают, где-то делаются дополнительные проверки на попадание индекса в диапазон, где-то еще какие-нибудь действия. Но факт в том, что даже в сверхвысокоуровневых языках массивы обычно максимально оптимизированы, это правда.