# Как работает получение значения по указателю?

Tags: c++, c, массивы, указатели, память

Вопрос возник еще на более высоком уровне - когда изучал скорость поиска в структурах данных и задал вопрос [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1178693/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%85%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF-%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B2-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0). Но ответ просто перекинул на уровень ниже от хеш таблиц к массивам, а от массивов к указателям/памяти, а идея осталась не понятна.

Разбирался с указателями и массивами очень давно и сейчас плохо помню практику, но что по адресу/указателю можно получить значение это вроде помню. Что конкретно происходило под капотом не особо понимал даже при использовании. Представляю массив как последовательность ячеек памяти аналогично сортированному набору:
[адрес=0x000, значени=9]|[адрес=0x001, значени=33]|[адрес=0x002, значени=82]|[адрес=0x003, значени=45]|...|[адрес=0xZYX, значени=12]

И не понимаю как можно как имея 0x003 или указатель на него получить значение за константу? Как это работает? Почему не за log2? Это завязанно на физическое устройство памяти? При этом вопрос не завязан чисто на C++, в других языках вероятно тоже есть массивы которые могут использовать что-то подобное не выставляя это на показ.

Comment: `Это завязанно на физическое устройство памяти?` Да. Очень-очень упрощёно: все ячейки оперативной памяти пронумерованы. Указатель хранит номер ячейки оперативной памяти. Когда нужно обратиться к i-той ячейке, то процессор аппаратно читает/пишет значение из/в i-ю ячейку за константное время. См.: [Random Access Memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory).

Comment: Было бы интересно узнать как именно этот процесс работает! Но теперь знаю куда копать, надеюсь год-два изучения вопроса и разберусь ;)

Comment: Это работает непосредственно в процессоре компьютера. В ассемблере есть команда, например, `mov eax,[ebx]` - это именно та команда, которая за один такт процессора (хотя не факт, может и за 10 тактов, разные команды работают за разное количество тактов) загружает данные в регистр `eax` из адреса в `ebx`.

Comment: *"как можно как имея 0x003 или указатель на него"* - указатель и есть адрес

Comment: *"Почему не за log2?"* Возможно где-то глубоко на уровне железа есть этот log2 от количества бит в указателе. Но бит всегда одинаковое количество, поэтому для вас время константное.